# Updating folder structure with Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, mkdir

I recently moved to a new folder structure for organizing my image folders. Now I need to update the folder structure, and I figured using mkdir would make my life a lot easier. There are quite a few folders from quite a few years so I try to avoid making this manually.

Currently the folders are in a form 2015/2015-06-10/image.jpg and I need to create 3 subfolders into each date (2015/2015-06-10/new-folder).

I tried using `mkdir -p 2*/*/new-folder` but that doesn't work. I think the wildcards are an issue here.

Thanks a lot :)

-Petri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

`for d in $(echo 2*/*); do mkdir "$d"/new-folder; done`